# Get patient details on combo box change

Tags: javascript, php, combobox

I need the code for getting the addr and pnum of the patient when I choose the pname in the combo box.

How can I do that?

```
<script>

function getVal() {
document.getElementById("text2").value = document.getElementById("model").value;
}
</script>   

<body>
//code in opening and getting my addr and pnum in dbase

<?php
include('connect.php');
$pname=$_GET['tpname'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblnpatient where pname='$pname'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $pnum=$row['pnum'];
        $addr=$row['addr']; 
}
?>

//code for choosing pname

<tr><td>Patient Name:
<div id="ma">
<select name="pname" class="textfields" id="model"  style="width:180px;"      onchange="getVal();">
<option id="0" >--Select Patient Name--</option>
 <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbnpatient");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    $pnum=$_GET['pnum'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblnpatient");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $pnum = $row['pnum'];
        $pname = $row['pname'];
 ?>
 <option id="<?php echo $pnum; ?>" value="<?php echo $pname; ?>"><?php echo $pname; ?>  </option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>

//code for getting pname and addr

Address:<input type="text" name="ename" size="20"  id="ma" value="<?php echo $addr ?>"/>
Name:<input type="text" name="ename" size="20"  id="ma" value="<?php echo $pname ?>"/>
```

Comment: Actually where you can stuck in here?

Comment: in opening my database and getting the pnum and addr of the pname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop add the following (if you have that column otherwise replace with something similar)
$paddress = $row['paddress'];

You can store the needed information by using the data attribute in your options

```
<option id="<?php echo $pnum; ?>" data-pname="<?php echo $pname; ?>" data-paddress="<?php echo $paddress; ?>" value="<?php echo $pname; ?>"><?php echo $pname; ?></option>
```

Then change your getVal() function

```
function getVal() {
  var options = document.getElementById("model").options;
  if (options.selectedIndex != -1) {
    var addr = document.getElementById('paddress');
    var name = document.getElementById('pname');
    addr.value = options[options.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-paddress');
    name.value = options[options.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-pname');
  }
}
```

Now change the id's of the input fields for the address and the name to paddress and pname. It is important to know to never have duplicate id's

I hope that helped

Comment: there's an error i m using this code for opening my database

Comment: <?php
 include('connect.php');
 $pname=$_GET['pname'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblnpatient where pname='$pname'");
 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   
    
    $pnum=$row['pnum'];
    $addr=$row['addr'];
    
    }
   ?>

Comment: Undefined variable: addr

Comment: because my paddress is addr

Comment: Ah yes, i'm sorry. Are you still getting errors after you fixed it?

Comment: my address is having a wrong address of the patient

Comment: Could you look in the sourcecode of the page itself and tell if the data attributes of the options are correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct..the output is when i reload the page there's an automatic address..